# Federated security, Single Sign On and security token sharing

Tags: wcf, security, single-sign-on, wif, ws-federation

In Single Sign On (SSO) scenario if all applications are running in same domain/company,

1. Is the same Security Token shared among all applications (relying parties) which get users authenticated from the same common identity provider / Security Token Service? What is the default behavior of any STS?
   E.g. User A logs on to application X. After some time, she tries to access the application Y. Since she is already authenticated by the same STS and if the token issued to her is still not expired, she won't have to provide credentials while accessing application Y.
2. My understanding is that it may be possible if the token contains ALL the claims which would be required by all relying parties / applications. But is it a good practice?
3. Can token's (which was issued when user logged on to application X) expiry time be extended/reset when user A connects to application Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIF implies ADFS usually,

1. Yes as long as all RP are using the same STS.
2. No - in ADFS, each RP has its own claims configuration. So the token produced is different (although you could simply copy the configuration if you wanted).
3. In WIF, yes. You need to use the "[sliding token](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2010/06/16/warning-sliding-sessions-are-closer-than-they-appear/)" mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am bit confused because in point # 1, you said that the same token is shared but in point # 2 you are saying that the different tokens are produced !
On point # 1: If the token is shared I think it will have all the claims which all relying parties need. Is it not incorrect to give information about the unnecessary/extra claims to the RP through the Security Token?

Comment: There are two things here. ADFS has session cookies which control authentication. The claims are sent as as SAML token. They are not the same. No, the cookie does not contain claims. No, claims are designed to send as many as you need.